# Which style is used to display an image after the text with alignment

Tags: css

```
<div class="caption_title_line"><h2 id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443674848657_279">
Clivuam tinc <img src="http://192.168.1.123/mth/moodle29/theme/newtheme/images/border-img.png" alt=""></h2>
</div>
```

I would like show text and image like the bellow link image.
http://s9.postimg.org/arc6wpzan/test.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this -

```css
*{margin: 0;padding: 0;}
body{background: #333;}
 
h2 {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
h2:after{
 background:#fff;
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    width: 100px;
}



/*h2:after{
    content: "";  This if you want to use the image
    height: 2px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    background: url(line.png);
}*/
```

```html
<div class="caption_title_line">
 <h2 id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443674848657_279">
  Clivuam tinc 
 </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="caption_title_line">
  <h2 id="yui_3_17_2_2_1443674848657_279">Clivuam tinc</h2>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  .caption_title_line{
           background-image: url('http://192.168.1.123/mth/moodle29/theme/newtheme/images/border-img.png');  
}
<style>
```

*And your image is not loading issue with image url*